# How to get all elements in document object MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have objects with users in my collection. Each document is a separate user that stores the username and category. Categories is an object that contains categories and costs. I need to get all categories in one user. How can i do this? find({ name: "Bob"}) finds all fields in the given document. And I need to take an object with categories and output the contents of category: {...} to the console. How can i do this?

```js
let users = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    сategories: {
      eat: "20$",
      entertainment: "100$",
    },
  },
];

mongoClient.connect(function(err, client) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  db.collection("users").find({
    name: "Bob"
  }.toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(result);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is getting logged, can you add that?

Comment: the entire object with the name "Bob" is displayed in the console with all fields. And I need it to display only the categories of a certain user, for example, find({name: "Bob", category}. And so that the console displays: eat: "20$", entertainment: "100$",

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a projection, in your find function:

```
mongoClient.connect(function(err, client) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  db.collection("users").find({
    name: "Bob"
  },{projection: {name: 0, _id: 0}}).toArray(function(err, results) { 
    console.log(results);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: With your code, I get the entire user object. And I only need to take his categories

Answer (score 1):

First, you are returning your data as `results`, and try to `console.log(result)`, which is different variable name.

If you want to take only `сategories` for each user in database and `console.log()` them, you can do it like this:

```
db.collection("users").find(
  { name: "Bob" },
  { сategories: 1 }
).toArray(function(err, results) {
  console.log(results.map(user => user.сategories));
  client.close();
});
```

**Note:** `results` will be an array of users because there can be multiple documents returned for specified query. `map()` is used to iterate over each item in `results` array, and map it to its `categories` property.